# how prevent close window for kendo scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, preventdefault, kendo-scheduler

i developped an ASP.NET MVC Application in my view, i have a scheduler

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<MeetingModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(new DateTime(2016, 4, 01))
    .StartTime(new DateTime(2016, 4, 01, 00, 00, 00))
    .Height(600)

    .Views(views => {
        views.DayView(d => d.Footer(false));
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Footer(false).Selected(true));
        views.MonthView();
        views.AgendaView();

    })
    .Editable(editable => {
        editable.TemplateName("EditMeeting").Destroy(false).Update(false).Resize(false);
    })
.AllDaySlot(false).Events(e=>e.Edit("scheduleEdit").Move("scheduler_move").MoveEnd("scheduler_moveEnd"))

    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m => {
            m.Id(f => f.IDMeeting);
            m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
        })
        .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler").RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
        .Read("Meeting_Read", "Meeting")
        .Create("Meeting_Create", "Meeting")
        .Destroy("Meeting_Destroy", "Meeting")
        .Update("Meeting_Update", "Meeting")
    )
)
```

when i validate the action of add meeting, i have a custom error which i add them to ModelState.AddModelError, the window for editMeeting closes.

```
 function error_handler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
        scheduler.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
            //prevent saving if server error is thrown
            e.preventDefault();
        })
        alertify.log(message, "error", 4000);
    }
}
```

how can I prevent the close of window, the window must not close when it has an error

Answer (score 0):

Basically the "error" event handler that you provide should work as the only way of preventing the edit window from closing is to prevent the next "dataBinding" event. Possible reason for current behavior might be the error event is not being thrown as you are not returning the model state errors inside the "Errors" field of the response. Here is the correct way of returning the ModelState errors back to the client side when using the "ToDataSourceResult" extension method:

```
return Json(new[] { meeting }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```